mdadm raid fails to assemble on boot (Ubuntu 24.04)
Mdadm raid is in inactive state after boot, with one drive missing (4/5).
$ journalctl -b | grep -E 'mdadm|md0'
(udev-worker)[706]: md0: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/md0' failed with exit code 1.

gives that, and after manually assembling; $ mdadm -A /dev/md0
kernel: md: array md0 already has disks!
kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdd operational as raid disk 0
kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 3
kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdf operational as raid disk 4
kernel: md/raid:md0: device sde operational as raid disk 1
kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdg operational as raid disk 2
kernel: md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 5 out of 5 devices, algorithm 2
kernel: md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 7814099968
mdadm[2784]: mdadm: DeviceDisappeared event detected on md device /dev/md/md0
mdadm[2784]: mdadm: NewArray event detected on md device /dev/md0

So i conclude that raid is working, but something is broken during boot, but what?
